# print button option is working in chrome not in firefox

Tags: html

Here is the code.

```
<button><a title="Print Screen" alt="Print Screen" onclick="window.print();" target="_blank"
       style="cursor:pointer;"><i class="black glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i></a></button>
```

print button option is working in chrome but not in firefox.

kindly guide me with best option to overcome this.

thanks

Comment: What you mean "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

HTML forbids placing interactive elements inside buttons or anchors. Both anchors and buttons are interactive elements.

When you make this error, browsers will recover from it in different ways. Firefox isn't recovering form your error in a way that will give you the effect you desire.

You aren't linking anywhere, so get rid of the `<a>` element and move the JavaScript you are binding to it to the `<button>`.

Comment: its working fine in firefox thanks.but i require a button which should show printpreview screen..for example in chrome while hitting print button print screen is appearing same wise if i hit the print button in firfox it should come print screen not print dialog box..i hope u understand

Comment: As far as I know, Firefox offers no API to display the Print Preview. Their UI has that feature though, so you can just let the user use that.